# innerText is undefined in jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

When testing using jest I saw that the property `innerText` is undefined while not in test it has the right value.

```
  it('get text from div', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('DIV')
    div.innerHTML = '<br>a<br>b<br>c'
    console.log('innerText', div.innerText) // undefined
    console.log('textContent', div.textContent) // 'abc'
    // expect(getTextFromDiv(div).length).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
```

But when using the same code not in jest test, the innerText shows :

```
'a

b

c'
```

and textContent is `'abc'`.

Why innerText in jest is undefined and when it's not in a jest than the value is real?

This is the code where it works (not in jest):

```
const addTextInRichTextToPdf = (doc, text, offsetY) => {
  const div = document.createElement('DIV')
  div.innerHTML = '<br>a<br>b<br>c'
  console.log('innerText', div.innerText) // print the real value
  console.log('textContent', div.textContent) // 'abc'
  ...
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you are using the default [testEnvironment](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string), then you are using jsdom.

You can check this issue to see why it is not implemented in jsdom :
https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1245

> The primary issue is the fact that innerText leans on the layout engine for guidance, and jsdom has no layout engine

If you want "full" browser support you can check [puppeteer](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/puppeteer.html#content)

Comment: Those looking for an alternative should consider `textContent` instead of `innerText`.

Comment: `textContent` helped solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: In 2021 prefer https://playwright.dev/ instead of puppeteer

Comment: @MatthewSouther yep I used textContent in my jest test and it found it, whereas innerText was returning null. Why does this work?

Comment: All I know is that `textContent` works. I think @GabrielBleu's answer gives a credible explanation as to "why".

Comment: `textContent` also helped solve my problem. Thanks!!

Comment: @MatthewSouther I'm using vitest and `textContent` worked, thanks!

Comment: MOST of the time you can indeed just use `textContent` instead of `innerText`.
BUT, there ARE differences:
`div.innerHTML = 'foo   <b>bar</b> <script>alert(1)</script> <p hidden>shh!</p><p style="visibility:hidden">secret</p><br><i>baz</b>'`
`div.innerText // 'foo bar\nbaz'`
`div.textContent // 'foo   bar alert(1) shh!secretbaz'`
Note the extra whitespace, content of script tag, handling of hidden elements, line breaks...
Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext

Answer (score 9):

Try using `textContent` instead of `innerText`

Answer (score 2):

Building up on Matthew Souther's answer, here is the code snippet I came up with to get the text of multiple dom children elements in one go:

```
const getInnerText = (element) => element?.textContent
          ?.split('\n')
          .filter((text) => text && !text.match(/^\s+$/))
          .map((text) => text.trim());
```

textContent brings a lot of noise, it returns an empty string when a html element has no text (or a string with only spaces). Therefore I filter the empty lines and the ones that contain only spaces (or tabs). I also trim the resulting entries. The reason I use question marks everywhere (optional chaining) is that, in case the text is missing, I prefer to get "undefined" as a result than an error thrown.

Here is how to use the function:

```js
const getInnerText = (element) => element?.textContent
          ?.split('\n')
          .filter((text) => text && !text.match(/^\s+$/))
          .map((text) => text.trim());

const div = document.createElement('DIV')
div.innerHTML = `
hello

world 
`;

const result = getInnerText(div);

// will display "world "
console.log(result?.[1])
```